# Can I disable variables' names autocomplete suggestions in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: autocomplete, wolfram-mathematica

By default, Mathematica makes autocomplete suggestions about variables' names as well as functions' names. It can be quite annoying because the pop-ups hide underlying lines and make editing long multi-line equations frustrating.
I've found the option for turning off all pop-ups (including functions). But can I specify what pop-ups do I want?

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the options below.  Modify `$FrontEndSession` to apply for just the current session.  Apply to `$FrontEnd` for future sessions too.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 CodeAssistOptions -> {"FloatingElementEnable" -> False}]
```

[image]